# Installing pynfft on Cygwin

Tags: python, installation, fftw, cygwin-64

I am trying to install pynfft 1.3 under cygwin but I am experiencing lot of problems.
I have checked that all the versions are updated. Has someone installed it under cygwin?
The main errors I get are of this type:

```
En el fichero incluido desde /usr/include/python3.9/pytime.h:6,
                       desde /usr/include/python3.9/Python.h:81,
                       desde /tmp/pip-install-hpyv9nzu/pynfft_14f5e5ee867d49c6be2bde9e599a38b9/pynfft/nfft.c:16:
      /tmp/pip-install-hpyv9nzu/pynfft_14f5e5ee867d49c6be2bde9e599a38b9/pynfft/nfft.c: En la función ‘__pyx_pf_6pynfft_4nfft_4NFFT___cinit__’:
      /tmp/pip-install-hpyv9nzu/pynfft_14f5e5ee867d49c6be2bde9e599a38b9/pynfft/nfft.c:3798:30: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
       3798 |   __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_v_self->_N);
            |                              ^~
                               ^
En el fichero incluido desde /usr/include/python3.9/unicodeobject.h:1026,
                       desde /usr/include/python3.9/Python.h:93,
                       desde /tmp/pip-install-hpyv9nzu/pynfft_14f5e5ee867d49c6be2bde9e599a38b9/pynfft/nfft.c:16:
      /usr/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:446:26: nota: se declara aquí
        446 | static inline Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject *op) {
            |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I have tried to install under different python, cython versions.